# How to access to Nuxt context from js file

Tags: vue.js, axios, nuxt.js

I make requests to the API in separate files, for example:

```
// ~/api/request.ts

import axios from 'axios'

export const testMethod = async (
  email: string
) => {
  try {
    return await axios.post('/test-route/', { email })
  } catch (error) {
    if (error.code === '401') {
      //
    }
  }
}
```

I want:

1. To add error handling, if the token has expired, then redirect to the authorization page and clear store.
2. Create axios instance with Authorization header, with token from Vuex

How do I access the Nuxt context from this file?

Answer (score -1):

I can suggest putting this logic to the vue mixin. Then you can interact with the vue/nuxt context.